# How can i parse a xml file in python

Tags: python, xml, jenkins

I have an xml file(basically the file is a jenkins slave config.xml file) from where i have to get certain values.
So, i tried parsing the `xml` file using `Element Tree` something like  this

```
tree = ET.parse(config.xml)
root = tree.getroot()
print root
for item in root.findall('slave'):
```

and then i am saving this parsed `xml` file in a text file, now i want to get the value within this tag 
I can do it through `bash` but i want to know how can we do this in python
Here goes the bash code

```
cat test.xml | sed -n 's:.*<label>\(.*\)</label>.*:\1:p'
```

Here is a sample jenkins slave config.xml file

```
<slave>
<name>some_name</name>
<description/>
<remoteFS>some_value</remoteFS>
<numExecutors>xx</numExecutors>
<mode>EXCLUSIVE</mode>
<retentionStrategy class="xxxx"/>
<launcher class="xxxxx" plugin="xxxxx">
    <host>xxx.x.x.xx</host>
    <port>xx</port>
    <credentialsId>xxxxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx</credentialsId>
    <maxNumRetries>0</maxNumRetries>
    <retryWaitTime>0</retryWaitTime>
    <sshHostKeyVerificationStrategy class="hudson.plugins.sshslaves.verifiers.NonVerifyingKeyVerificationStrategy/></launcher>
    <label>some_label</label>
</slave>
```

Similarly as label i need other values as well such as hostname, port etc.

Comment: The example `config.xml` is not a valid XML file. Getting error in `<sshHostKeyVerificationStrategy xxxxxxxxx/>`. Error: `Attribute name "xxxxxxxxx" associated with an element type "sshHostKeyVerificationStrategy" must be followed by the ' = ' character.`. Attach a valid XML file.

Comment: edited with the correct format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate recursively using `.iter()` to find elements. Check [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#finding-interesting-elements).

Here is an example to print the `label` and `host` text from `slave` node.

**Update**: The `code.py` is modified to additionally print `class` attribute value of `launcher` tag. It uses `element.attrib` to get the attributes of a tag. More can be found in [official documentation of parsing XML](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml).

`test.xml`:

```
<slave>
    <name>some_name</name>
    <description/>
    <remoteFS>some_value</remoteFS>
    <numExecutors>xx</numExecutors>
    <mode>xxx</mode>
    <retentionStrategy class="xxxx"/>
    <launcher class="xxxxx" plugin="xxxxx">
        <host>xxx.x.x.xx</host>
        <port>xx</port>
        <credentialsId>xxxxxxxx</credentialsId>
        <maxNumRetries>x</maxNumRetries>
        <retryWaitTime>x</retryWaitTime>
        <sshHostKeyVerificationStrategy class="hudson.plugins.sshslaves.verifiers.NonVerifyingKeyVerificationStrategy"/>
    </launcher>
    <label>somelabel</label>
</slave>
```

`code.py`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse("test.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for item in root.iter('slave'):
    for label in item.iter("label"):
        print label.text
    for host in item.iter("host"):
        print host.text
    for launcher in item.iter("launcher"):
        print launcher.attrib["class"]
```

Output:

```
somelabel
xxx.x.x.xx
xxxxx
```

Comment: how can i get the launcher class from here?? for launcher in item.iter("launcher"): does not seem to be working

Comment: Updated the answer to show the class attribute of `launcher` tag.